# AppTranslation in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

How can I use a nested words from my JSON with using `AppTranslations.of(context).text("xxx)`?

my JSON:

```
{
    "user":{
        "name":"NAME",
        "first_name":"FIRSTNAME",
        "last_name":"LASTNAME",
        "email":"E-MAIL",
        "account_name":"ACCOUNT NAME"
    },
}
```

I want for example use `name` from this json, i try use it in this way:

```
AppTranslations.of(context).text("user[0].name")
```

but it not work :/

thanks for any help

//////////////////////////////

Comment: You can't call user[0] since it's an object, not an array

Comment: I know, but u must use object in my JSON, have you any idea how can I do thsis?

Answer (score 0):

In your `AppTranslations.dart` you can add this method after the `text()` method.
The method will help you get value through the type of nested Json in your question.

```
String mapText(String key){
    List text = key.split(".");
    return _localizedValues == null?"":_localizedValues[text[0]][text[1]] ?? '** $key not found';
  }
```

After adding that to `AppTranslations.dart` you can call it like this

```
AppTranslations.of(context).mapText("user.name")
```